# StackOverflowError while configuring a custom UserDetailsService

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

**Problem**: When I use an in-memory user details configuration, everything works. As soon as I try to use a custom UserDetailsService, I get an infinite loop when authenticating.

---

I've created a simple application with Spring Security's OAuth2 package handling authentication. Here's a quick look at the configuration.

I needed an authorization server, so I created a simple one with an in-memory store of client credentials for my app:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.inMemory()
        .withClient("myApp")
        .secret("");
  }
```

Next, I wanted the TokenEndpoint to be able to use a ResourceOwnerPasswordTokenGranter for my users' credentials. The only way I could get that to happen was to set an AuthenticationManager in the endpoints configurer:

```
  @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationManager authManager;

  @Override
  public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
    LOG.info("Adding authManager");
    endpoints.authenticationManager(authManager);
  }
```

Finally, I configure my AuthenticationManager to have an in-memory set of user credentials, as outlined [in the Spring Docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html):

```
  @Configuration
  public static class UserPasswordAuthConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      LOG.info("Adding userDetailsService");
      auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
          .withUser("me")
          .password("horsebatterystaple")
          .authorities("ALL_POWER");
    }
  }
}
```

With this setup, I can run the project just fine. In the logs, I see `Adding userDetailsService`, followed by `Adding authManager`, and my credentials are accepted as I would expect. When I change the configuration to use a custom UserDetailsService, things go wrong. All I change is the `UserPasswordAuthConfig`:

```
  @Configuration
  public static class UserPasswordAuthConfig extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      LOG.info("Adding userDetailsService");
      auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }
  }
```

When I run this, I never see `Adding userDetailsService` in the logs, telling me that it never runs my `init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method. I also see this:

```
AuthenticationManagerBuilder : No authenticationProviders and no parentAuthenticationManager defined. Returning null.
```

When I try to get a token, I get infinite recursion:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:227) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor71.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy87.authenticate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

While I'm debugging through it, I see that the AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer creates a set of default token granters. While doing so, I noticed that the configurer has a reference to an AuthenticationManager that is a proxy...of itself

[image: Debugger with infinite proxies]

---

I have two main questions:

- Why doesn't Spring run my `init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` method when I change it's *contents*?
- Why do I get crazy errors when I switch to my CustomUserDetailsService? Am I misconfiguring something?

Comment: Well, I was using `spring-cloud-starter-parent` version `Brixton.RELEASE`. When I updated to `Camden.RELEASE`, the problem went away.